# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport.isMtls()

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, dependency-management

This is not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68703855/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-boolean-com-google-api) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65826798/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-google-api-client-http-httptransport-ismtlsz)

my pom.xml has only two dependency .but somehow in run time i am getting
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport.isMtls()'
at com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery$Builder.chooseEndpoint(Bigquery.java:6381)

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${google.cloud.bom.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.***.sharepoint</groupId>
    <artifactId>sharepoint-util</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
    </dependency>




</dependencies>
```

i have checked in dependency tree there are no conflicting version of the jar.
attaching dependency tree. i have tried to add the scope as provided in maven but other bigquery imports are failing with noclassdeffound error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------< AA>--------------
[INFO] Building AA 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]----------------- 
 ----------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ AA
 ---
[INFO] *******g:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.***.sharepoint:sharepoint-util:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.json:json:jar:20180813:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:30.1.1-jre:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:jar:v1-rev20210127-1.32.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.7.3.2.6.5.0-292:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.7.3.2.6.5.0-292:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26.hwx:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26.hwx:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-sslengine:jar:6.1.26.hwx:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:runtime
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  |     \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |     +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.jamesmurty.utils:java-xmlbuilder:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:jar:5.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.microsoft.azure:azure-keyvault-core:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.4.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.7.3.2.6.5.0-292:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:4.41.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-kerberos-codec:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-i18n:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.directory.api:api-asn1-api:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.apache.directory.api:api-util:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.54:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.htrace:htrace-core:jar:3.1.0-incubating:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6.2.6.5.0-292:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.7.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] \- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core:jar:2.0.5:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:jar:3.17.3:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-iam-v1:jar:1.0.14:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:jar:1.39.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:3.17.3:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-http:jar:2.0.5:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.32.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.31.5:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-apache-v2:jar:1.39.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:jar:1.39.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.api:gax-httpjson:jar:0.86.0:compile
[INFO]    +- io.opencensus:opencensus-api:jar:0.28.0:compile
[INFO]    +- io.grpc:grpc-context:jar:1.39.0:compile
[INFO]    +- io.opencensus:opencensus-contrib-http-util:jar:0.28.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.39.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.4:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.39.2:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.14:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.5.5:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery:jar:v2-rev20210726-1.32.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.api:api-common:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO]    +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO]    +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.8.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.api:gax:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.threeten:threetenbp:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO]    \- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.971 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-06-07T22:35:29+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "localDeploy" could not be activated because it does not exist.
```

Comment: @Samuel Negri can you help

Comment: Which version of the Google Cloud BOM are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was order of dependency declaration, since my sharepoint declared first it always picked the class that got loaded first. The exclusion tag wont help as well , since its excluded at runtime.

Comment: What was the fix here?

Comment: change the order and declare  the dependency with correct version before everything else